# Print automatically the JSON Keys only instead of its values Using React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I got a project where I have to print the complex nested JSON files "Keys" only instead of its values. The number of files is multiple and each file has more than 300 lines which are hard to be completed manually. Normally when I am printing JSON data, so I am doing complete mapping like the below example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
const data = [
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    }
];
class PrintJsonObjects extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid" style={{ backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7' }}>

                <table id="table-to-xls" className="table table-responsive table-striped display nowrap"  >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">PPU</th>
                        <th scope="col">Batters</th>
                        <th scope="col">Topping</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.map((record) => (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{record.id}</td>
                            <td>{record.type}</td>
                            <td>{record.name}</td>
                            <td>{record.ppu}</td>
                            <td>
                                {record.batters.batter.map((item) => (
                                    <p>Id: {item.id} - Type: {item.type}</p>
                                ))}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {record.topping.map((item) => (
                                    <p>Id: {item.id} - Type: {item.type}</p>
                                ))}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

```
export default PrintJsonObjects;
```

Here is the Output:
[image]

Well, In the above example I am doing complete mapping manually for each object to print its values on the screen.
Now, what I want is to print just the attributes names "Keys" instead of its Values, and incase of nested objects, I want to put a "." dot between each attribute and print it. Basically, I want to print the mappings of the JSON objects. Also, I want this job to be done automatically by just providing the data. I want the output data just like the below example:

```
Id,
type,
ppu,
batters.batter.id,
batters.batter.type,
topping.id,
topping.type,
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this works for you: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-givjf?file=/index.js:623-973)

```
const keys = [];
const getKeys = (element, topLevelKey) => {
  Object.keys(element).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof element[key] === "object") {
      if (Array.isArray(element[key])) {
        element[key].map((item) =>
          getKeys(item, topLevelKey ? topLevelKey + "." + key : key)
        );
      } else {
        getKeys(element[key], topLevelKey ? topLevelKey + "." + key : key);
      }
    } else {
      keys.push(topLevelKey ? topLevelKey + "." + key : key);
    }
  });
};
data.map((element) => getKeys(element, ""));
console.log([...new Set(keys)]);
```

Comment: Hi @Medi. Thank you so much for your help. Works for me. Just one problem. The nested objects are going to the next line. Is there any way to put the nested objects after the parent attribute by just dot in between? eg: batters.batter.id

Comment: Thank you so much. Now It is working as I want. Ton's of thanks dude

Comment: Hi @Medi. Just one last problem. Incase of 3 level nested objects, it is returning the last two keys and drops the first level parent key. Eg: Incase of "batters.batter.Id" it is giving me "batter.Id". It is losing the parent "batters". I have upto 5 levels of nested keys. Please help. thanks

Comment: @AnonymousUser I updated again the answer. if it doesn't work. please create a sandbox example so I can work on it.

Comment: Hi @Medi . I have no words to thank you. Dude, you have no idea that you have not only solved my big problem but saved my time. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AnonymousUser I'm glad I was helpful to you :D.

Answer (score 2):

There is a native `js` function for this, `Object.keys()`,

You can find more info at [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object/keys)

This method will return only the `keys` of the objects you have, any custom functionality
you need can be added by using this function

Comment: Hi @Rohan. Thanks for your response. I have tried there using the link but it is just returning the level 0 keys only not the nested ones.